# How to convert LINQ Query Generic List of Anonymous objects to IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Repository Method and I am trying to convert a LINQ query ToList result to my return type with no avail. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
    IDBEntities DBContext;
    public ProjectRepository(IDBEntities db)
    {
        DBContext = db;
    }
    public IEnumerable<project> SelectAll(bool? is_debug_mode, int? performed_by_id)
    {
        var projects = (from p in DBContext.projects
                        join o in DBContext.organizations on p.organization_id equals o.organization_id
                        join m in DBContext.members on o.organization_id equals m.organization_id
                        where m.member_id == performed_by_id
                        select new
                        {
                            p
                        }).ToList();
        return (IEnumerable<project>)projects;
    }
}
```

The error I receive is:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`1[NameSpace.Data.project]]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NameSpace.Data.project]'.

Comment: that should be `select p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `p` in linq query is of type `project`

```
var projects = (from p in DBContext.projects
                join o in DBContext.organizations on p.organization_id equals o.organization_id
                join m in DBContext.members on o.organization_id equals m.organization_id
                where m.member_id == performed_by_id
                select p).ToList();
return projects;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, that did it. I am new to using LINQ extensively and had been stuck on this for several hours.